# Store functions to array resulting in scope trouble

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to store some functions to an array. I want to achieve something like this:

```
    class Store {
    constructor(){
        this.storage=[];
    }
}
let store1=new Store();
let store2=new Store();

(function (store1) {
    store1.storage.push({"func1":function () {func2();}})
})(store1);

(function (store2,store1) {
    store2.storage.push({"func2":function () { console.log('func2');}})
    let func2 = function () { console.log('func2');}
    let func1= store1.storage[0].func1
    // let func1= function () {func2();}
    func1();


})(store2,store1);
```

The problem is that it throws 'func2 is not defined' because of a scope problem I think.

Is there a way to keep this code structure or behaviour ? I need to store functions like this.

Comment: `(function (store1) {
    store1.storage.push({"func1":function () {func2();}})
})(store1);` this code is throwing. there is no `func2` defined in the scopes accessible by this code. What are you trying to build here? Your code gets pretty weird after you've instantiated the stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way without changing to much code would be creating a namespace like:

```
class Store {
    constructor(){
        this.storage=[];
    }
}
let commons = {};
let store1=new Store();
let store2=new Store();

(function (store1) {
    store1.storage.push({"func1":function () {commons.func2();}})
})(store1);

(function (store2,store1) {
    store2.storage.push({"func2":function () { console.log('func2');}})
    commons.func2 = function () { console.log('func2');}
    commons.func1= store1.storage[0].func1
    // let func1= function () {func2();}
    commons.func1();
})(store2,store1);
```

I'm not sure about your exact use case, but maybe you should consider putting those method inside your class or restructuring the code in a way that functions are defined in the same scope?